# In Python, how do I ensure that the used modules are available in target machines?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Often times, after developing a python script that use few specialized modules, I find that I have to let the end-party know about the dependencies and let them install them before running the script. 
Is there anyway (similar to setup.py [and managing with pip]) that I can supply along with that will validate and ensure that the required modules are present before executing the script? Is there a pythonic way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean *"similar to setup.py"*? Why don't you... provide a setup.py?

Comment: Have a look at wheels http://pythonwheels.com/

Comment: I wanted to know the alternatives, but yes, I have used setup.py & let pip manage it.

Answer (score 0):

You could always check if they have the dependencies, and if not, download it from the code. Example for `pandas`, but can be used with any module:

```
try:
    import pandas as pd
except ImportError:
    import pip
    pip.main(['install', 'pandas'])
    import pandas as pd
```

you might also want to take a look at [`cx_Freeze`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze) which turns your code into an .exe